# Tkinter Optionmenu StringVar.get() returning blank

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am creating a Tkinter window with a 'for loop' so it can self-adjust if later on, I decide to add more questions. My issue is that I can't save the inputted value on the optionmenu. So far all I got was a `list1 = ['', '', '']` while the `Strg_var = [StringVar, StringVar, StringVar]` and it prints only the blanks and the variables PY_numbers.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

LARGE_FONT = ("Arial", 12)

window=Tk()

def _save():
    print(*list1, sep = ", ")
    print(*Strg_var, sep = ", ")

Questionlist = ["A. Is A true? :", "B. Is B true? :", "C. Is C true? :"]          
choices = ['-', 'Yes', 'No'] 
n = 0
Strg_var=[0]*len(Questionlist)
list1=[]
for n in range(len(Questionlist)): 
    Label(window, text=Questionlist[n], font = LARGE_FONT, background = "white").grid(row= n, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady = 10, sticky="W")
    a = tk.StringVar(window)
    OptionMenu(window, a, choices[0], *choices).grid(row = n, column=2, padx=10, sticky="WE")
    list1.append(a.get())

tk.Button(window, text="Save", command = _save,width=18).grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, sticky="W")

window.mainloop()
```

Can someone help me to sort this out on how to save the optionmenu user selections into a list or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list of `StringVar`(Do Initialise them, I haven't done that in my code). Every time an option is selected the corresponding item will change. So I would do it like this.

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Arial", 12)

window=tk.Tk()

def _save():
    print(list(map(lambda x: x.get(), a)))

Questionlist = ["A. Is A true? :", "B. Is B true? :", "C. Is C true? :"]          
choices = ['-', 'Yes', 'No']
a = [tk.StringVar(window) for i in range(len(Questionlist))]
n = 0
for n in range(len(Questionlist)): 
    tk.Label(window, text=Questionlist[n], font = LARGE_FONT, background = "white").grid(row= n, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady = 10, sticky="W")
    Strg_var = tk.StringVar(window)
    tk.OptionMenu(window, a[n], *choices).grid(row = n, column=2, padx=10, sticky="WE")

tk.Button(window, text="Save", command = _save,width=18).grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, sticky="W")

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Output:

`['No', '-', 'Yes']`

Comment: One issue that appeared is that if user decides to change its answer the list won't understand that, so I can't manipulate the end result, which is one of the objectives of the program. Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: @RafaelCasteloBranco Edited my answer. See if it fits your description.

Comment: Thanks! it worked with a small adjustment as the list becomes a local variable and I can't work with it, but setting it as a global variable 'z' makes the charm work 
 def _save():  global z    z= list(map(lambda x: x.get(), a))  print(z)